# Can I override task :environment in test_helper.rb to test rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, testing, rake, bdd

I have a series of rake tasks in a Rakefile which I'd like to test as part of my specs etc. Each task is defined in the form:

```
task :do_somthing => :environment do
  # Do something with the database here
end
```

Where the :environment task sets up an ActiveRecord/DataMapper database connection and classes. I'm not using this as part of Rails but I have a series of tests which I like to run as part of BDD.

This snippet illustrates how I'm trying to test the rake tasks.

```
def setup
  @rake = Rake::Application.new
  Rake.application = @rake
  load File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../tasks/do_something.rake'
end

should "import data" do
  @rake["do_something"].invoke
  assert something_in_the_database
end
```

So my request for help - is it possible to over-ride the :environment task in my test_helper.rb file so I my rake testing interacts with the my test database, rather than production? I've tried redefining the task in the helper file, but this doesn't work.

Any help for a solution would be great, as I've been stuck on this for the past week.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My "solution" to a similar problem was to extract all the logic from my .rake files and create classes to perform the tasks, leaving just a one-line call in the rake file, which I felt confident in not testing too hard. The classes could then be tested pretty much normally.

I don't know how well this would stand up to a complex set of interdependent tasks that maintain some far-reaching state: probably not well, but then again that would most likely be an indication of some other design problem...

I'm curious to see if I've missed something better.

EDIT: There used to be a blog post [here](http://blog.innerewut.de/2009/3/2/what-to-put-into-rake-tasks) that (a) says the same thing and (b) says it better. Looks like he said it first, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike. I've done some more messing around with Rake in the mean time, and I think these two methods in test_helper.rb might be some way towards a solution.

    def rake_up
      Rake.application = Rake::Application.new
      Rake::Task.define_task :environment
      Rake.application
    end

    def rake_down
      Rake.application = nil
    end

Comment: The link to that blog post appears to be dead. The only place I could find the contents is here: [What to put into Rake tasks](http://www.artima.com/forums//threaded.jsp?forum=123&thread=251328)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this line:
require(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'config', 'environment'))
it's exactly what you find in "task :environment" implementation

I use it to test my rake tasks using rspec

Answer (score 0):

when you are running tests environment is that is being loaded is test.

> so you are interacting with test
>   database only.

So i dont see any reason to override your rake task in test_helper.rb