# Test Rake Tasks

Tags: ruby, testing, rake

I am developing a ROR app that relies on many custom Rake tasks.

What is the best way to test them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Rake tasks are pretty hard to test. The easiest solution would be to move the logic into a method in an appropriate model. You can then test that and just call the method from the rake task.

Comment: I think this is a decent suggestion, but it doesn't answer the question.  You shouldn't have to pollute your models to run batch scripts, etc. on your data.

Answer (score 17):

Something like:

```
  def execute_rake(file,task)
    require 'rake'
    rake = Rake::Application.new
    Rake.application = rake
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
    load "#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/#{file}"
    rake[task].invoke
  end
```

At your spec:

```
execute_rake("tags.rake","tags:popular")
```

Comment: rake[task].invoke instead of rake[tags].invoke

Comment: awesome answer. That load thing did the trick when testing rake tasks for a gem.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  This works, until you need to use rake to run your tests.  In that case your tests will fail silently with a non-zero exit code, but rspec will report all tests pass.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty well covered in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925407)

My recommendation, repeated here in summary, is not to try testing rake tasks: extract the code to be tested to a class, model or lib function and test it there. Then just use rake to call the functions and manage dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [PivotalLabs' way](http://pivotallabs.com/how-i-test-rake-tasks/) the most. However, I generalized and modified their code as followed in my app:

```
# file: spec/tasks/my_rake_file_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rake'

describe 'my_rake_file.rake' do
  before :all do
    Rake.application.rake_require 'tasks/my_rake_file'
    Rake::Task.define_task(:environment)
  end

  let(:run_rake_task) {
    Rake::Task[task_name].reenable
    Rake.application.invoke_task task_name
  }

  describe 'my_task_name' do
    let(:task_name) { "my_task_name" }

    it "creates 10 cars" do
      run_rake_task
      Car.count.should == 10
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I extracted the heavy lifting of my_rake_file.rake's code to a module, which is stored in lib/

Answer (score 0):

Well, now there's a Gem for that:

> Fantaskspec  - https://github.com/crismali/fantaskspec

Answer (score 0):

Rake tasks **do** need testing, especially if you do some batch processing in it. Testing them is quite easy these days:

```
class CleanExamsTaskTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def test_deletes_results_of_old_exams
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('2010-07-05 10:00')
    @exam.update!(end: Time.zone.parse('2010-07-04 09:59'))

    assert_difference -> { @exam.answered_questions.count }, -1 do
      capture_io { run_task }
    end
  end

  def test_output
    travel_to Time.zone.parse('2010-07-05 10:00')
    @exam.update!(end: Time.zone.parse('2010-07-04 09:59'))

    assert_output("Exams processed: 1\n") { run_task }
  end

  private

  def run_task
    Rake::Task['exams:clean'].execute
  end
end
```

[Full example](https://github.com/internetee/accreditation_center/blob/master/test/tasks/tests/clean_test.rb)

Tested with Ruby >= 1.9 and Rails 5.2. Uses `Minitest` from `stdlib`. No other dependencies.