# Test seeds.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec2, seed

Before updating production, I need to ensure, that all manipulations, performed with seeds are working correctly.

How do you test seeds.rb with RSpec?

Comment: Poor quality question. Reformulate, correct typos.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what you mean by "manipulations", but my guess it that you're question really boils down to "how to test a rake task" (in this rake rake db:seed). For that, check for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255176/test-rake-tasks

Comment: By manipulations, i mean altering some records, a priory existing in DB. I need to test, that the code works properly.

Answer (score 0):

A seed is intended to be run first on an empty database, to correctly give the correct state. If that initial state needs to change (e.g. domain tables) you have to adapt the seed accordingly that it can add non-existing elements or change existing elements. A good way to achieve this is to do something like:

```
admin = Operator.find_or_create_by_login!(:admin) do |adm|
  adm.name = 'admin'
  adm.is_administrator = true
end
```

Before running the tests, we also load the seeds, so then it is easy to create a spec that will verify that the needed data is there (in case you wouldn't trust it).

If you need to manipulate existing data the preferred way is to use a migration. I generally do not write specs for migrations, but test them on my development database, and on a copy of my production database (before running it on top of actual production).

Hope this helps.